# Why next.js does not tell me which Image lacks src property?

Tags: next.js

Next.js is awesome. But it has bugs that drive developers crazy.

I'm creating a website and I have used `next/image` like in 25 places.

And now I get this error:

```
Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received: {}
    at Image (webpack-internal:///../../site/node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js:157:19)
    at renderWithHooks (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5471:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5544:15)
    at renderElement (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5759:7)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5898:11)
    at renderNode (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6030:12)
    at renderHostElement (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5456:3)
    at renderElement (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5765:5)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5898:11)
    at renderNode (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6030:12)
error - ../../site/node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js (159:18) @ Image
```

It literally does not tell me anything about my source code.

How am I supposed to debug this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code. probably you did not accept the next/image format. Just add src like that:

```
 <Image
  loader={myLoader}
  src="me.png"
  alt="Picture of the author"
  width={500}
  height={500}
/>
```

Comment: I checked all of my `Image` tags and all of them have the `src` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your node_modules folder and then, install packages with **npm i**, I think there would be an issue that u have don`t passed the src props in any image tag, try to debug the src props that should be wrapped in **src = {}**

Comment: I did that but it made no difference.