# Is it possible to access the hierarchy of parents in React?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have this component:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
    return <div>hi</div>
}
```

Can I somehow know parents' hierarchy of it?

**Reason for asking**

Yesterday I asked [Why next.js does not tell me which Image lacks src property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036583/why-next-js-does-not-tell-me-which-image-lacks-src-property).

A solution came to my mind. The solution is to create a custom `SmartImage` component that wraps the Next.js `Image` component.

Here's the code:

```
import Image from 'next/image'

const SmartImage = (props) => {

    if (!props) {
        console.log(props)
        throw new Error('Props should be provided')
    }

    if (!props.src) {
        console.log(props)
        throw new Error('Src is not provided')
    }

    return <Image {...props} />
}

export default SmartImage
```

I hoped that by explicitly throwing errors, Next.js would give me a useful callstack that I could use to find out which image has no `src` or which image's src from API is null.

However, I still get this response:

```
Error: Src is not provided
    at SmartImage (webpack-internal:///./Base/SmartImage.js:18:15)
    at renderWithHooks (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5471:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5544:15)
    at renderElement (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5759:7)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5898:11)
    at renderNode (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6030:12)
    at renderHostElement (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5456:3)
    at renderElement (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5765:5)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5898:11)
    at renderNode (/site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6030:12)
error - Base/SmartImage.js (12:14) @ SmartImage
```

Which is still not useful at all.

So, is there a technique that I can use in `SmartImage` to somehow render the hierarchy of its parents?

For example `App => Index => Services => div => Service`.

I know I can ask developers to provide a unique description for each image. But if we can make it dynamic, it would be much more valuable.

Comment: You should use typescript. (You can generate a ts next project, look at nextjs doc). And by the way, prop is always an object and never falsy.

Comment: @AlexandreNicolas, do you mean that by using typescript I can access the parent's hierarchy in my component?

Comment: Not really, but the Image component props will be typed and you will not be able to declare an <Image /> without the required props (describes here https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#required-props).

Comment: @AlexandreNicolas, the problem is that in a real-world project where 50 `<Image>` tags are used and API might be empty for any reason, it's extremely difficult to find out what data is missing. But if it tell us where the problem is in our code, we could definitely solve it within minutes.

Comment: If everything is hardly typed, the only issue can come from the data source. If you want to guard your data type, don't do it inside a component do it when you get response from your API with JOI or something else.